# extra space after footer inconsistent across pages

Tags: jquery, html, spring-boot, twitter-bootstrap-3, thymeleaf

I have a website running and I updated the code about 2 days ago, all of a sudden I had this large space after the footer on some page only, the other pages seem to work perfectly. I tried everything but it has nothing to do with padding or bootstraps box model. Anyways I'm using thymeleaf and jquery. I suspect it has to do with scripts. Please view here,  https://tajili.co.za[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ3wI.png)

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: very strange - the browser tools show no element at this position, and none of the elements above it has a margin or similar that could cause this, also the html element finishes above that area...

Comment: I've used chrome's profiler to see if I could find something... And there seems to be something specific happening in about google maps, but did not investigate further, you'll want to check it out tough. Also, I see you had an anti ad-blocker or something... So I disabled my adblocker to see, and still same result BUT I saw an arrow to go to top of the page, which is not present when ads are blocked.

Comment: @Xolani... Please use "row" class in between "container" & "col-*". Since you are not using it that may be one of the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an element with classes "dropdown-menu open" inside the a `form` with attribute `action="/classifieds"`. It has a generated height of 2671px, and in it's CSS it has `visiblity: hidden`, which still causes it to occupy that space (while not showing its contents).

If you can erase that and replace it by "display: none", the problem will be solved. But actually, since it's a rule in `material-kit.min.css` you probably can't change it, so you have to overwrite it by adding the following rule to your custom CSS:

```
.btn-group.bootstrap-select .dropdown-menu, .dropdown .dropdown-menu, .dropdown-menu.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget, .dropup .dropdown-menu {
    visiblity: visible;
    display: none;
}
```